# Django CMS: How to avoid SITE_ID to be set in settings?

Tags: python, django, django-cms

We are using **Django CMS** for a while, and need to migrate our website to a multi-site implementation with Django Sites framework. We wanna use [CurrentSiteMiddleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/sites/#site-middleware) to detect which site is used (based on subdomain). In result we will have a `request.site.id` set by middleware that is based on the current user request to our website.

I've tried to find the best way how to use Django CMS without forking it, and didn't find a good way how to do this.

What do we actually need:

- each **Page** can be used on the current Site, or **on few sites** at the same time. To do so, Django documentation recommends to add **M2M** FK to the **Site** model from each Article object (in our case, it's the Page object). But the `TreeNode` has the FK to the `Site` model, that means that only one Page can be mapped to a single site. But we need to map one Page to one or few sites at the same time.
- we want to use [Django Sites framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/sites/), because Django has it built-in and creators of Django use it on their projects (and it's for what is was designed - to map some object to one or few sites at the same time). In my opinion it's very clear approach to have a multi-site solution running on the same instance of the web app.
- we need to have a single instance of the app, because we have shared plugins that we need to use across multiple organisations (each organisations has it's own Site on subdomain).
- we plan to have hundreds of organisations using our shared codebase, and it's unable to run a new instance for each new subdomain. Also it's harder in maintenance, upgrading, etc. But looks that Django CMS in current implementation is able to work only per one instance with set `SITE_ID` in the `settings.py` file.
- when we **remove SITE_ID definition from settings.py**, Django can't start the web server because Django CMS uses `get_current_site()` and `get_site_id()` -- trying load `SITE_ID` value from the settings file. I'm trying to mock such usages, but wanna to find a better approach for this.

Please, help us to find the way how to continue use of Django CMS, without writing our own CMS-like bicycle solution. We generally like Django CMS and wanna continue use it in our 5-years old social project.

Need your help.

Answer (score 0):

After a few days of investigation I went to conclusion that Django CMS is designed in a way that `SITE_ID` property is mandatory to be set in `settings.py` file. In many places it’s no access to the request object, from where we can potentially recognize which site is used to make the request.

Only way that I’ve found is to dynamically change settings in my own middleware on each incoming request. It’s very weird practice, but because Django CMS is actively used in our website and we can’t replace it straightforward — we need to use this hack way, at least now. And Django app needs to be run in a single thread to achieve this approach.

Idea is borrowed from the `django-multisite` project.